# K-stability on Fano fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric

> **Motivation**:  Let $\pi:X\to B$ be a holomorphic fibre space. By theorem 1.3 of Kawamata, if the central fibre be of the general type then all the fibres are of the general type see
>   http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9809091.pdf , this tells you that if the
>   central fibre $X_0$ has Kahler-Einstein metric with negative Ricci
>   curvature, then all the fibres have Kahler-Einstein metric with
>   negative Ricci curvature.
>
> Or, if the central fibre $X_0$ be a Calabi-Yau variety with canonical
>   singularities then all the fibres $X_t$ are also Calabi-Yau variety
>   with at worst canonical singularities. See
>   [Fibration when central fibre is a Calabi-Yau variety with canonical singularities](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245334/fibration-when-central-fibre-is-a-calabi-yau-variety-with-canonical-singularitie)
>
> This means that if the central fibre has Ricci flat metric then all
>   the fibres must have Ricci flat metric,
>
> So it is natural to see what will happen for Fano fibration, like Mori
>   fibre space, when the central fibre admit Kahler-Einstein metric with
>   positive Ricci curvature and to ask all fibres $X_t$ admit
>   Kahler-Einstein metric with positive Ricci curvature?

**Question**: Let $\pi:X\to B$ be a Fano fibration with Fano projective varieties $X,B$, such that $X$ is K-stable and central fibre $X_0$ admit Kahler-Einstein metric, then my conjecture is that, all the fibres must admit Kahler-Einstein metric. Is there any counter-example?

Huristicly it must be correct.

> More comments with motivation of this question: Huristicly Let $f:X\to Y$ be a Fano fibration such that
>   $X$ and central fibre $X_0$ admit Kahler-Einstein metric, then
>   Semi-positivity of fiberwise Kahler-Einstein metric along Mori-fibre
>   space $\pi:X\to Y$ is equivalent to K-stability of projective variety
>   $X$ when Fano central fibre admit Kahler-Einstein metric If this is
>   OK, then K-stability is equivalent to invariance of plurigenera due to
>   existence of solution of "relative Kahler Ricci flow"
>
> $$\frac{\partial \omega(t)}{\partial
>  t}=-Ric_{X/B}(\omega(t))+\omega(t)$$
>
> along Mori-fibre space.